# How to check and validate mandatory parameters in the query from the service layer while sending graphql request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have a scenario as, my qraphql query has few mandatory parameters and when I send a request without mandatory parameter, GraphQL directly returns the error message as a stack trace response. But instead of this behaviour, in my service layer, I have to validate my incoming query request and validate the input parameters. If the mandatory parameter is missing in the query, have to send an error/response message as " field is missing!".. Can I achieve this by using graphql-kickstart-java?

Example:
Schema:
type User {
userId: ID!,
userName: String!,
account:String!
}

type Query {
getUser(userId: ID!, account: String!) : JSON
}

Request:
{
getUser(input: userId:1) {} //account is missing in the request which is mandatory.
}

Comment: you can remove `!` for non mandatory fields

Comment: just search for your server error customizations ?